# Serve web service response to download as file

Tags: python, django, web-services, django-views

I have a template where I render a response from a web service.

```
def XMLResponseView9request):
    ...
    with open(archivo_request,"r") as archivo:
         request_data = archivo.read()

    headers = {'Content-type':'text/xml'}
    data_response = requests.post(target_url, data=request_data, headers=headers)
    jdato = xmltodict.parse(data_response.content)
    data_xml = data_response.text
    data_template = json.dumps(jdato)

    return render_to_response('response.html',
                              {'data':data_template,'dataxml':data_xml},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Beside of render the response I want to serve the response as a file (xml or txt) to be downloaded.

I try passing the response as text (variable: data_xml) and served through a simple javascript function, but the file is empty or only have one line "[object Object]".

Is possible serve the response as file from the DJANGO view instead of passing the text to the template.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want the xml file to be downloaded by the browser, right?

Comment: yes, I want be able to choose to download the file or only read the file in  the template, because sometimes the response have a lot of information or a little information. The response depends of the WS previously selected for the user

Answer (score 0):

To make a file downloadable, you just need to change one HTTP Header, Content-Disposition.

```
def some_view(response):
    xmlFile = open(pathout, 'r')
    myfile = FileWrapper(xmlFile)
    response = HttpResponse(myfile, content_type='application/xml')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+filename
    return response
```

Comment: I have a doubt. I need to create other view to pass the response and made it able to download or I can use the that I am using actually. Following your suggestion how can pass the variables and the template name.

Comment: So you want to show it on a page and there give a download button?

Comment: yes. I try passing the data to the template, but when I download the file only say `[object object]`